# CSS replace previous adjacent selector

Tags: css

There are two variants of a div:

```
<div class="parent">
   <span>some stuff</span>
   <div>Important element</div>
   <div class="unit">xxx</div>
</div>
```

and:

```
<div class="parent">
   <span>some stuff</span>
   <div>Important element</div>
</div>
```

What would be a working CSS selector for the Important element `<div>` only if the `.unit <div>` is present in the `.parent <div>`? I want to apply some formatting in that case. Unfortunately the .unit  comes after the other div and I cannot select the preceding element.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
}

.parent > div:not(.unit):last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <span>some stuff</span>
   <div>Important element</div>
   <div class="unit">xxx</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <span>some stuff</span>
   <div>Important element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works, thank you very much!!!  Of course, I did use `.parent > div:not(.unit):last-child` otherwise the rest of the page is all red ;-)  Is there an additional possibility to select the .parent <div> for formatting as well, in case the .unit is present ?

Comment: @DirkAlbrecht, nope, you can't make selector for parent. But depending on what are you going to do with it, you may find some other hack to achieve that. Also, if your problem is solved, accept corresponding answer by clicking a checkmark on the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

`nth-last-child` is what you want assuming that you will always have the variants your are showing.

```css
.parent > :nth-last-child(2):nth-child(2) {
  color:red;
}

.parent {
  border:1px solid;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <span>some stuff</span>
   <div>Important element</div>
   <div class="unit">xxx</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <span>some stuff</span>
   <div>Important element</div>
</div>
```